# Laravel Irregular Plural Model Name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have run into a problem that I have no thought about before, what do you name a model when it is an irregular plural word?

I am tinkering with mobile app with the Ionic Framework and am using Laravel for my backend. I want to implement a news tab which will just display quick snippets about what is going on. In Laravel, I want to have a NewsController and a news model to correlate with it. Typically the model is a singular version of your DB table, so what do you do when the word doesn't really have a singular version, like news? Would it be acceptable to name the model 'New' or would something like Article be the more susceptible way to handle this?

Comment: Why it's "Newses", precious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is no problem - you can use `protected $table = 'my_news';` in your `News` model (and that table name can be totally different than model name) . More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions). Your model can have arbitrary name (singular/plural) however usually singular is used.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, I haven't ran into this issue until now and it made the gears start turning in my head. Made me curious what others did when it came down to this.